# Add an alias for LAN/WLAN IP

Tags: webserver, hostname

Right now Apache server is listening on port 80. I want people on the same network to access the site as random.xyz but without making that my actual hostname (which is ubuntu right now).

The manual for hostname isn't really giving much insight. Is there any way to achieve this?

Adding a name under `/etc/hostname` only works locally (so I can now type `http://minsky` and get the site. Something like this would be ideal:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu minsky #this sets aliases for the machine, but on the lan we can only use the IP address.
192.168.1.33 minsky
```

But **minsky** isn't recognized by other devices. Only **ubuntu**

Comment: You could use a [zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) setup, for example with [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)). But you'd probably have to setup a client on each machine you want to be able to resolve the address. It might be easier to just edit the `/etc/hostname` (or similar) of each client.

Comment: just to be clear, i want to link my LAN IP (192.168...) to another name other than the machine name @HenningKockerbeck. Just found something similar here https://superuser.com/questions/1093419/alias-for-ips-in-the-home-lan-network but can't check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname you specify on the server does not have to relate to how other systems would find your system. /etc/hostname is only one of the name resolving mechanisms. Usually a DNS server is used. Some of the DNS servers provide a way to add local entries based on DHCP leases. So when the host asks for an IP address it is added to the DNS server, but this depends on your setup.

mdns/avahi/zeroconf as suggested works without dns server. But I would prefer a dns server which resolves whatever hostname you want to point to your webservers ip address

Comment: Okay I will try, thanks for the suggestion